# Undefined variable: ticketinfo

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting the following error:

> Undefined variable: ticketinfo (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\violation\resources\views\records\show.blade.php)

I don't know how to fix it. :(

This my html code:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Ticket No.</th>
      <th>Type of Violation</th>
      <th>Violation Code</th>
      <th>Violation Name</th>
      <th>Apprehending Officer</th>
      <th>Remarks</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>{{ $ticketinfo->ticketno }}</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is my Controller code

```
public function show($id)
{
    $ticketinfo = ticket::find($id);
    return view('records.show', compact('ticketinfo'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You did `compact('tickets')`, but your variable is called `$ticketinfo`.

Do `compact('ticketinfo')` instead. The naming matters.

Comment: Typo, i did compact('ticketinfo') sir.

Comment: Copy/paste the code, don't retype it. Who knows what *other* typos you may have made?

Comment: I'm trying to show two table values in one controller, maybe something is wrong with my code.

Comment: The code you've shared doesn't show any of that, so I suspect your issue lies with what you're *not* showing us. The error indicates `$ticketinfo` is not being properly sent to the view.

Comment: "Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\violation\resources\views\records\show.blade.php)"

Now im getting this error.

Comment: `$ticketinfo` is probably null, then. Maybe there's no record by that ID.

Comment: I fixed it, my problem now is relations. Instead of showing only the related value for that ID it shows all of values.

Comment: btw thankyou for helping me. appreciate it.